# Return a value from a Listeners onSuccess() in Kotlin (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, listener, return-value

I try these tutorials: https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md, especially the function `getUserSignatureInfo`. In this function a REST API call (`userSignaturesGetUserSignature`) is made.

In my code below I try to return a value (`userSignatureId`) I get from REST API. I understand, it's impossible this way, because `onSuccess()` will be invoked later as the outer function getUserSignatureInfo() returns.

I want to call `getUserSignatureInfo()` from a `Fragments` `onActivityCreated()` and use this value on creating a RecyclerView.Adapter.

The question is, what is the (best practice) way to do something like this: make a REST API call, wait for response, and use the response in further code.

```
// my Fragment
...
...
val userSignatureId = getUserSignatureInfo()
recyclerView.adapter = createMyAdapter(userSignatureId)
...
...



// function where the REST API call is made
fun getUserSignatureInfo(context: Context) : String {
    val eSignApiDelegate = DocuSign.getInstance().getESignApiDelegate()
    val usersApi = eSignApiDelegate.createApiService(UsersApi::class.java)

    val authDelegate = DocuSign.getInstance().getAuthenticationDelegate()
    val user = authDelegate.getLoggedInUser(context)

    var userSignatureId = ""

    eSignApiDelegate.invoke(object : DSESignApiListener {

        override fun <T> onSuccess(response: T?) {
            if (response is UserSignaturesInformation) {
                val userSignature = (response as UserSignaturesInformation).getUserSignatures().get(0)
                Log.d(TAG, "Signature Id: " + userSignature.signatureId);

                // My problem: this assignment is useless 
                // because the outer function getUserSignatureInfo()
                // returns earlier as onSuccess()
                userSignatureId = userSignature.signatureId
            }
        }

        override fun onError(exception: DSRestException) {
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
    }) {
        usersApi!!.userSignaturesGetUserSignature(user.accountId, user.userId, "signature")
    }
    
    // This is my problem: userSignatureId is empty because 
    // onSuccess() fires later as this function returns  
    return userSignatureId
}
```

Thank you much!

Comment: The best practice is for this logic to be in a viewmodel or repository, and for the fragment to eventually find out the result by some reactive API (`LiveData`, RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.). Please understand that your REST call may take several seconds, depending on the Internet connectivity of the user and the state of the relevant portion of the Internet between your user and the server.

Comment: Thank you, CommonsWare! Maybe I will try a solution with LiveData, so I build a empty RecyclerView at first, then fill the LiveData from the REST API and fill this way my RecyclerView with data from the REST API. But the solution of jyorien works well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could pass a callback into getUserSignatureInfo(), for example

```
fun getUserSignatureInfo(context: Context, callback: (String)->Unit) : String {
    val eSignApiDelegate = DocuSign.getInstance().getESignApiDelegate()
    val usersApi = eSignApiDelegate.createApiService(UsersApi::class.java)

    val authDelegate = DocuSign.getInstance().getAuthenticationDelegate()
    val user = authDelegate.getLoggedInUser(context)


    eSignApiDelegate.invoke(object : DSESignApiListener {

        override fun <T> onSuccess(response: T?) {
            if (response is UserSignaturesInformation) {
                val userSignature = (response as UserSignaturesInformation).getUserSignatures().get(0)
                Log.d(TAG, "Signature Id: " + userSignature.signatureId);

                // return the value in the callback
                callback(userSignature.signatureId)

            }
        }
```

When you want to use the string value from another class,

```
getUserSignatureInfo(context) { id ->
  Log.d("test", id)
}
```

Comment: Thank you much! I've seen this solution but I thought it looks too easy :-). It works well!!!

Comment: great! thank you!!

Comment: great! Save the day!